# How To Index Management in Magento 2 on Local Server?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, reindex, php-5.4

I need to reindex but can't get it to work. I'm in the root directory and when running:

```
magento indexer:reindex
```

It states that magento isn't a valid command, so after further research I try and run the php command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But I get the same error saying php isn't recognised as an internal or external command.

I haven't got WAMP or XAMP installed as I believe it is running on PHP's built in web server? It is running on a mapped network drive at Y:.

I know this is vague but it's all the information I've got to go on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add this as a comment, but don't have the reputation required...

I've had similar issues that came up due to permission issues before. Make sure all your files have the recommended permissions set on them and the proper ownership assigned to them.

Have you tried running the command using sudo?

Comment: I'm running Windows and not Unix so sudo isn't a command.

Comment: 'Run as' would be about the equivalent, I assume. I haven't touched a windows machine in a few years.. Did you happen to have any luck messing with permissions?

Comment: You can't run it as admin because you need to be the correct user to access the network drive. Permissions seems fine - I don't think it's a permissions problem! It's just my lack of knowledge in this area as there is no WAMP or XAMP installed.

Comment: You can run the command prompt as admin though, right? Also, when attempting to run the php command, are you in your magento root directory? The commands won't be found without being in the magento root

Comment: If it's not permissions related, It may be an issue with your %PATH% variable, this issue may be able to get you on track. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows

Comment: If I run the command prompt as admin I can't access the magento root directory.